# Module 'pandas' has no 'read_csv' member pylint(no-member)

Tags: python, pandas

my code snippet is as below. Im unable to proceed with **error** `"Module 'pandas' has no 'read_csv' member pylint(no-member)"`. Can someone help here?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
filename = "data.csv"
headers = ["Test1","Test2"]
df = pd.read_csv(filename, names = headers)
df.head(5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to check is that you don't have your own files named pandas.py or csv.py which could conflict here. If you are sure that you do not, then you could check if your user account has rights to your python lib folder.

If the problem is not there, you could try reinstalling pandas with pip-autoremove:

```
pip install pip-autoremove
pip-autoremove pandas -y
pip install pandas
```

---

(Linux only)
I also read that for somebody it helped to remove package and then reinstall with
sudo. However, if possible, I would suggest not to use sudo when not needed.

```
pip uninstall package
sudo -H pip install package
```

Comment: This solved my problem. I have created a file with name pandas.py. I have renamed it and its working fine now. Thank you.